# Get name of tracking branch + remote name

Tags: git, github

I am looking to discover a git command that can give me information on the upstream remote and branch name.

if I run

```
git branch
```

or

```
git branch -v
```

neither tell me which remote branch are tracked by this local branch.
I am looking for a git command which can tell me the remote and remote branch name that would originally be determined by

```
git push -u x/y
```

where x is the remote name and y the branch

does this make sense?

(What happens if there are multiple remote branches being tracked? I would guess that only one remote can be tracked by a local branch?)

Comment: Yes only one remote branch can be tracked by a local branch. "Tracking" sort of means "is used as the default for pull and push". There is nothing you can do with a tracking branch that you can't also do with other branches, albeit with a few extra required parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use the `-vv` switch of `git branch` command.

This will print list of local branches with more information including what each branch is tracking and if your local branch is ahead, behind or both (the command doesn't reach reach out to the servers so numbers can be wrong).

```
$ git branch -vv
* master 02d9483 [origin/master] sort by category
* test   56b413a just a test
* trackb d789ad2 [origin/trackb: behind 1] another test
```

> What happens if there are multiple remote branches being tracked? I would guess that only one remote can be tracked by a local branch?

I believe there is no way to track several remote branches with a given local branch. You can emulate this behaviour by writing a custom script

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use the following git command:

```
git remote show origin
```

This will give you all the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens if there are multiple remote branches being tracked? I would guess that only one remote can be tracked by a local branch?

Since it is possible to add multiple remotes to a working directory in git, I think it's safe to say that multiple remote branches can be followed by a branch.

For instance, consider the following configuration for a local repository :

```
git remote add origin_one [url_origin_one]
git remtoe add origin_two [url_origin_two]
```

Then, suppose we have checked out to `master` branch locally and want to push the changes. Not surprisingly,

```
git push origin_one master
```

or

```
git push origin_two master
```

will push the changes to master branch, on the origin_one and origin_two, respectively.

If you want to see what tracking branches you have set up, you can use the `-vv` option to `git branch`.

This will list out your local branches with more information including what each branch is tracking and if your local branch is ahead, behind or both.